# Export Map to GeoPDF

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geopdf

I am using GeoServer/OpenLayers to build a map website. One of things I want to do is to export a map to GeoPDF. It's not an export from desktop software. More specifically, map tiles are added as images and GML features are added as vector data. The only thing I have found that could allow me to do that is TerraGo SDK.

Has anybody tried to do the same thing? Could anybody shed some lights?

Thanks,

Comment: I suspect you mean to ask how to produce a geo-spatial pdf, not a geoPDF. geoPDF is a trademark and the only way to produce one is using tools from TerraGo, I believe. The most notable difference between the two (as I understand it) is that the TerraGo geoPDF is enabled for some nice annotation capabilities using the TerraGo toolbar, as well as some more powerful re-projection capabilities. These are not available in a generic geo-spatial pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoServer can produce PDFs, but not geospatial ones. If someone wants to give a crack at an implementation here there are some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184127/java-itext-geospatial-pdf-exporter

Answer (score 4):

Starting with version 2 [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html) can create Geospatial PDF's.  It is also able to request images directly from WMS servers to retrieve the information from Geoserver.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented openlayers map export with the features here..
you can register and check it here at www.mapsdata.co